# How can create a nested layout builder in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am making a flutter application where the user will be able to drag and drop different components like row, column, text, textbox etc from the inspector menu (left) into the viewport (right). The problem is can't figure out how to handle nested components like a row inside a column or a textfield inside a column etc. I guess i need to use a recursive function which will build the layout, but i am not sure about it

I already made a function which can serialize the layout (once it's lid out into the viewport) into a json, so that i can save it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.